# how to calculate the xmldata?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, elips-studio

i'm getting the xmldata from the httpservice (using cgi) and i have not set resultformat(it is coming as an object only),the xml data in this format

```
<root>
<employee name="xxx" age="xx" gender="xxx"/>
<employee name="xxx" age="xx" gender="xxx"/>
<employee name="xxx" age="xx" gender="xxx"/>
</root>
```

when i was tried to count the employee tag,i getting the problem, my code will like this:

```
var i:int=o;
for each(var obj:object in event.result.root.employee)
{
 i++;
}
```

i getting the count as 3  but the problem it give the count as 3 when the coming data i.e)the xml data is

```
<root>
<employee name="xxx" age="xx" gender="xxx"/>
<root>
```

actually i want to count the number of employees tag not all subtag ,
i hope you may save my time
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

event.result.employee.length()

or look here for .ChildNodes
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/xml/

or another one
http://www.underground-flash.com/2008/02/arraylength-vs-xmllength-in-as3.html

and one more professional
http://www.thetechlabs.com/tutorials/xml/working-with-xml-e4x-and-actionscript-3/